# Pre-compiled assets (manifest.yml) not being detected on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline

Since I'm running my app on the Bamboo stack I'm precompiling my assets and committing them.

I've included the file manifest.yml in public/assets/ but heroku doesn't detect it. As a result it tries to compile assets and borks itself.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I discovered that I was trying to serve up unprocessed files from the public directory. 
Also, I migrated my app to cedar which helped too. :)